# Difference between Canvas and Grid to Move, Resize, Rotate UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, resize

I want to develop a editor that can add dynamically Controls and after to move, resize or rotate to build a window with this UIElements.

**My question is who is better for a Container of this UIElements, a Grid or a Canvas?**

Canvas are working in absolute position, maybe have better precision for transforming. But is less responsive when I will display the App in different screen resolutions? I doesn't know very well about the pros/cons from Grid or Canvas.

I made a example with a Canvas and Grid to move a UIElement with this code:

```
private void ui_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_IsPressed)
        {
            UIElement ui = (UIElement)sender;
            TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
            transform.X = Mouse.GetPosition(MyGridOrCanvas).X;
            transform.Y = Mouse.GetPosition(MyGridOrCanvas).Y;
            ui.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
    }
```

But with the Canvas or Grid, when I click the UIElement and without moving, the UIElement always moved x,y from my cursor. Maybe isn't the best way to do this. **If you have also tutorials about how to build this features will help me too.** I'm new with this stuff.

Thank you very much and greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just provide a short answer for this question as [it is likely to be closed by the community here for being too subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I can see one close vote already.

So, in my opinion, the `Canvas` is a much better control to use for this purpose. For one reason, it does not have the considerable layout requirements of the `Grid` and so it is more efficient. The other main reason is that using the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties to move the items is perfect... to move items in other `Panel`s, you often have to make do with setting the `Margin` property instead, which is far from ideal.

As for your items moving when being clicked on... that's just a bug in your code doing that, it's *not* the normal behaviour - a control won't move on its own unless we tell it to.

Comment: Thank you! In addition I read this article that can be important for other people with the same question. Greetings! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646962.aspx