# How to set inherited parent property for a Control Child on Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

After I decide to which Container I will use to load my Controls, a Canvas. [From my previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231044/difference-between-canvas-and-grid-to-move-resize-rotate-uielements)

I began to search on google about how to move, resize a UIElement on a Canvas. First article was written from **Josh Smith**, [Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas).

When I finish to read it and tray the example. It wasn't what I was exactly looking for but it was very close. After I came across with the article from **igkutikov**, [Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387977/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas), who had the same situation and made a very useful class who manage all methods to build a dragable canvas. Finally I decide to use this class and adapt to my project.

*Tip: For who are learning how to build a canvas with dragable controls. It's hig recommended to read and study this 2 previous articles*

In the article from igkutikov, to use the "DragCanvas.cs" class, we define the namespace who the class is placed. A continuation we implement in our project the DragCanvas who is a interface about [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
<tools:DragCanvas x:Name="UCDragCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black">
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Move me" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="40" tools:DragCanvas.CanBeDragged="True"></Button>
    </tools:DragCanvas>
```

So, in the example above, **when we add a Button, we can set the Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top and DragCanvas.CanBeDragged properties, that are properties from his parent.** This parent is our UCDragCanvas Container.

**My question now is, how I can do it from code behind?**

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "Move me";
// ToDo add UCDragCanvas Properties for btn.
UCDragCanvas.Children.Add(btn);
```

Thank you very much and greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 30);
...
DragCanvas.SetCanBeDragged(btn,true);
```